# How to calcualte the Fourier Transform of a Gaussian pulse with a nonlinear chirp

Tags: fourier-analysis

I have a Gaussian pulse with a nonlinear chirp:

$$
e^{-t^2} Cos(50 t - 8πe^{-2t^2} )
$$
or in a general form:
$$
e^{-t^2} Cos(a t - b e^{-2t^2} )
$$

My problem is to find the Fourier transform of this formula in an analytical form.  Thanks a lot in advance.

One related numerical solution is here:
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/99670/how-to-calcualte-the-fourier-transform-of-a-guassian-pulse-with-a-nonlinear-chir：